# With Firestore and Firebase cloud functions, how do you iterate over documents with a specific ID nested into a subcollection?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, google-cloud-functions

The stack used is:

- Firestore
- Firebase cloud functions
- Typescript
- Listening document changes

Each of our users have a copy of the posts he favorited at path:

```
user/{userId}/favorites/{postId}
```

When we edit a post, a function is triggered and iterate trough our active users to update the posts in favorites with the same postId.

My idea was to iterate over users

```js
const modifiedPostId = ourModifiedPost.id // from listener
const await activeUsers = firebase.db.collection('users').where('active','==',true).get()

for (const user of activeUsers) {
    const await samePostIdUserFavorite = firebase.db.collection(`users/${user.id}/favorites/${modifiedPostId}`).get()
    if (samePostIdUserFavorite.exists) {
         await copyPostToUserPosts(user, modifiedPostId)
    }
}
```

The issue there is that only some users have it in favorite so we are making an enormous amount of reads for nothing.

I tough of another way but there I cannot found how to limit my search on active user and I'm not even sure that it could work ?!?

```js
const modifiedPostId = ourModifiedPost.id // from listener

// I'm calling a collection but actually get one document in a specific sub-collection from all parent collections...
// I don't see how this could work at all
const sameIdFavorites = firebase.db.collection(`users/{userId}/favorites/${modifiedPostId}`)}.get()

for (const favorite of sameIdFavorites) {
    // I have no idea how to get userID
    await copyPostToUserPosts(userId, modifiedPostId)
}
```

Is there a way to fecth only the posts from **'users/{userId}/favorites/{favoriteId}'** where **user.active === true** and **favoriteId === modifiedPostId**?

Or at list to satisfy only the last condition: **favoriteId === modifiedPostId** without reading the entire user database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to fecth only the posts from 'users/{userId}/favorites/{favoriteId}' where user.active === true and favoriteId === modifiedPostId?

With your current schema, no, it's not possible.  Firestore does not support SQL-like joins between collections, even if they are nested with each other.  A query may only consider contents of documents in a single collection (or collection group) at a time.

You could copy the "active" flag down into each nested document in "favorites", then use it as a filter there.  Duplicating data like this is fairly common in NoSQL type databases that don't support joins.

> Or at list to satisfy only the last condition: favoriteId === modifiedPostId without reading the entire user database?

With your current schema, again, no.

You could instead include the ID of each favorites document as a field within that document, then use it as a filter in a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on favorites.

Assuming that the field "id" contains the document ID wihin each document of "favorites":

```
firebase.db.collectionGroup("favorites").where("id", "==", modifiedPostId)
```

This will give you all the documents among all subcollections called "favorites" that have the ID given in `modifiedPostId`.